# Regex: replace everything after underscore

Tags: regex

files are named like

```
name date _ uniqueid.pdf
```

result should be

```
name date _ somethingelse.pdf
```

I'll be using a find/replace so don't worry about the replace part. I just want to search matching the underscore.

**This is NOT for c# .net, it is for find and replace in another program that accepts regex.**

**I'm really sorry I should've mentioned this. No languages, just plain regex. ie. /[^_].***

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example not taking into account any invalid characters in a file name

```
[^_]*_(.+)\..+
```

Group 1 of that regex would return uniqueid in your first example. If you want to capture the file extension as well you can use the following.

```
[^_]*_(.+)
```

**Edit:**

C# Example with Regex.replace

```
//With file extension option
Regex.Replace(Test, "([^_]*_).+(\\..+)", "$1somethingelse$2");

//Change file extension option
Regex.Replace(Test, "([^_]*_).+\\..+", "$1somethingelse.pdf");
```

Comment: I feel like this should work but it replaces everything instead of just replacing the last part of the name starting from _ (underscore) to end of string. I just need the last underscore up to the end of string excluding the ".pdf" removed

Comment: ya it would because it matches the whole the string but group1 matches what you are looking for if wanted to replace string at the contents at group1 that would work

Answer (score 0):

This might be a silly question, but is there anything wrong with

```
r = /name date _ [[:alnum:]]+.pdf/
```

(Ruby style)

Answer (score 0):

assuming this regex is for .net c#

```
Regex.Replace("name date _ uniqueid.pdf",@"(?<=_ )(\w+)(?=\.pdf)",@"somthingelse");


(?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
  _                        '_ '
)                        end of look-behind
(                        group and capture to \1:
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
)                        end of \1
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
\.                       '.'
  pdf                      'pdf'
)                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: The given example has a space after the underscore `_ ` further more it's not quite clear if _uniqueid_ can have some special characters…

Comment: Can you specify the regex flavior your program uses. It may not support lookaround feature as .net C# does…

Comment: simple regex. sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
/^(.*_)[^_]+(\.pdf)$/$1somethingelse$2/
```

Answer (score 0):

in the Ruby

```
z = "name date _ uniqueid.pdf"

z2 = "somethingelse"

z.gsub(/(.*_\s*)[^_.]*(.[a-zA-Z0-9]*$)/,'\1'+z2+'\2')
```