# Regex to match part of file name

Tags: regex

I need to use regex match expression to find part of a file name.

eg file name is **ABC01-001-M-001_0.dwg**

I need to match the first digit after the underscore (this is the revision number of the drawing file name)

In this case with the example it would match the **0**

Can anyone please advise the regex for this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491087/regex-replace-everything-after-underscore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*pushpraj* answer is almost correct. I take it you dont want to see the underscore.

so `(?<=_)(\d+)` would be the correct choice. The `(?<=_)` says, that the underscore have to be in front of your desired pattern but not included.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/kH1nE2/2

Comment: There is nothing wrong with his answer! Outside the `()` is non capturing but matching. So `_()` means match a underscore but do not capture. See for yourself: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/giu

Comment: @Andreas Oh, that's true. It declares a capturing group. Until now, i thought of it just to border operators. Thanks, i learned sth. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be pretty simple.

```
_(\d)
```

online demo https://regex101.com/r/kH1nE2/1

in case you expect more digits you can use the following

```
_(\d+)
```

note "+" which will match 1 or more digits after underscore

Answer (score 0):

In this case regex is not even needed.

```
$n = "ABC01-001-M-001_0.dwg";
Echo intval(explode("_", $n)[1]); // 0
```

https://3v4l.org/fBXc5

It seems you are looking for a javascript solution?

```
var n = "ABC01-001-M-001_0.dwg";
var int = parseInt(n.split("_")[1]);
```

Not sure it actually works because I'm not doing writing in javascript but ^^ is what I could google about the functions.
Maybe works, maybe not.

It seems to work :-)
https://jsfiddle.net/w9x7d40f/